# getTokenAccountsByOwner hangs

Tags: validator, rpc

When calling `getTokenAccountsByOwner` through RPC on my own validator, the request hangs forever. When I call `getBalance` it works fine, and when I call `getTokenAccountsByOwner` on mainnet-beta it works fine. What would be the problem?

I've tried to index the accounts by `--account-index spl-token-owner` but it takes more than 128G of RAM.

See my test code bellow

```
# all fine
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getBalance",
    "params": [
      "myAccountPubkey"
    ]
  }
'

# all fine
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
    "params": [
      "myAccountPubkey",
      {
        "mint": "7dHbWXmci3dT8UFYWYZweBLXgycu7Y3iL6trKn1Y7ARj"
      },
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed"
      }
    ]
  }
'
# hangs 
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
    "params": [
      "myAccountPubkey",
      {
        "mint": "7dHbWXmci3dT8UFYWYZweBLXgycu7Y3iL6trKn1Y7ARj"
      },
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed"
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Account-data RPC requests that scan the entire account set perform poorly when not indexed.  This has to do with the high number of populated accounts. I experienced without indexing it can take up several minutes for a single call!

By default starting a validator/rpc these accounts are not indexed. Use the `--account-index spl-token-owner` parameter to speed up `getProgramAccounts` and `getTokenAccountsByOwner`. Please note, enabling this requires >100GB of RAM.

Here some more background in the solana docs:
https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start#account-indexing

Comment: I've tried it, now it need at least 256G (my 128G RAM was full and swap was fill up to 128G aswell)

Comment: Yeah, its 100GB on top of the general RPC usage. If you want to run an RPC with all these indexing features, you need preferably 512GB of RAM. If you use swap with an nvme drive you can use less, but also performance will be less.

Comment: Hey @omega, I was thinking of hosting a RPC only node in VPS. Can you maybe suggest any VPS where I can do it without being overcharged and thing I should know?

Comment: @MuhitRaihan currently its nearly impossible to run an RPC on a VPS, as you need >256 GB of RAM and lots of compute to keep up with the network. There are light clients under development which can eventually do with less, but AFAIK there is none on the market right now which is runnable on a cheap VPS.

Comment: @Omega I found one which I think can run a RPC node https://www.latitude.sh/metal/pricing . Can you maybe check and let me now if it really can support one?

Comment: @MuhitRaihan those are bare metal. The AMD 7443P can run Solana RPC node yes. c3.large.x86

Comment: @Omega so I can setup a RPC only node on that one right? Can you link me to any how to full guide on how to setup a RPC node??

Comment: @MuhitRaihan Here https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5281/hello-there-im-wanting-to-setup-a-solana-rpc-node-could-anyone-please-tell-me

Comment: To add on RPC nodes, you can also run one with Chainstack free on the Developer plan https://chainstack.com/protocols/solana/

Answer (score 1):

Found the [answer on the discord](https://discord.com/channels/428295358100013066/837340113067049050/989435605211570206) from `linuskendall | Triton One#8823`. I need indeed to specify `--account-index spl-token-owner`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Solana stackexchange. Could you also add the relevant parts of the discussion to this answer? We prefer the answers to be self contained. Thanks :)