# Hello there, I'm wanting to setup a Solana RPC node, could anyone please tell me where I can find docs or any helpful material?

Tags: solana-cli, solana-test-validator

I was using Quicknode in my site, although there is a huge traffic incoming & I think Quicknode wont be able to sustain.

Would like to create my own node endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Solana has docs for this that should be able to help you get started! I also included some other helpful resources for RPC nodes specifically

https://docs.solana.com/running-validator

https://www.solana-validator-guidebook.com/solana-introduction/what-is-an-rpc-node

https://www.solana-validator-guidebook.com/validator-setup/rpc-startup-command

https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/solana-nodes